# Basic algebra. Please help.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $1200$ is divided by $N$ and $N+x$, the remainder in both cases is $35$.

What is the maximum value of x?

Comment: Since you are new to this site, please consider reading this: [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) I wrote this comment because the question sounds homework-like.

Comment: martin, Yes I am new to this site. This question *sounds* homework like but it is not. I am preparing for a competitive exam, and so, I asked this because I didn't know , what is the correct way to do this problem. I accept your code-of-conduct and conditions very truthfully and I promise, I will try to show my work, so that it does not sound like a homework question. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What can we say about $1200-35=1165$ in relation to $N$ and $N+x$? Particularly with regards to divisibility.

**Hint 2**: Look at all factors of $1165$, see what you can say.

Answer (score 2):

When 1200 is divided by any number greater than 1200 remainder is 1200.
When 1200 is divided by (1200-35)=1165 remainder is 35.
Again when 1200 is divided by 233 remainder is 35.So greatest value of x is 1165-233=932

Comment: Depending on the competition, that is not sufficient. You've shown that x=932 is a possible value of x, but how can you show that it's the maximum?

Answer (score -1):

I will use Haskell to brute-force this problem. Here's an extremely brief GHCi session:

```
Prelude> [ n | n <- [1..1200], 1200 `mod` n == 35]
[233,1165]
```

Because $1200 = (233 \times 5) + 35 = 1165 + 35$. Since $1165-233 = 932$, we have $x = 932$. Alternatively, we could have used a sexier list comprehension, as follows:

```
Prelude> [ x | n <- [1..1200], x <- [1..(1200-n)], 1200 `mod` n == 35, 1200 `mod` (n+x) == 35]
[932]
```

The interpretation of these "experimental" results is left to the reader.